# Rails 5: timeout when booting app on localhost with vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, localhost

I'm trying to move my app from Cloud 9 to Localhost. This is what I've done so far:

1. installed Vagrant 1.9.1 and Virtualbox 5.1.12. on my Windows 10
   64bit
2. with Vagrant installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 and Postgresql 9.5
3. with `rails db:setup` created DB from my schema

In terminal I can boot Rails server with `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` and it starts correctly:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When I open `http://localhost:3000/` it gives me error of timeout
`Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException in LandingController#index`

and points to line in my `landing/index.html.erb` like this:

`<img src="<%= image_path('landing/laptop.png') %>" alt="laptop"/>`

In terminal I see this message:

```
Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException (Request ran for longer than 20000ms):

app/views/landing/index.html.erb:51:in `_app_views_landing_index_html_erb___1903502845453706848_40657680'
app/controllers/landing_controller.rb:6:in `index'
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (11.6ms)
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (46.7ms)
source=rack-timeout id=989422929f6047c15c931fac986f4ae0 timeout=20000ms service=22077ms state=completed
```

Assets are in place as previously in Cloud 9 - I did no change anything.
I thought it's something with sprockets, so I re-installed that, but no luck - error stays.

**How do I fix this, please?** Thank you!

**Update**

There is nothing special in controller:

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index]
  skip_before_action :get_role, only: [:index]

  def index
    render layout: 'empty'
  end
end
```

**Update 2**

The error stays even when I move my app to RailsInstaller for Windows, so I assume Vagrant is not to blame in my case. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? It seems to me there is something related to that I've copy+pasted app from Cloud 9 where I had caching on.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing a couple of times? One thing I have seen is that `Rack::Timeout` might raise an error while assets are still compiling for the first time. We just disable it in development mode.

Comment: Refresh did not help. I put `config.assets.enabled = false` in config\environments\develoment.rb but it did not help either.

Comment: @lobati It seems the error is not related to Vagrant as there is same error when I boot my app from RailsInstaller without VM. Could it be something related to Caching?

Comment: Can you try disabling `Rack::Timeout`? You can add a `config/initializers/rack_timeout.rb` with the line: `Rack::Timeout.service_timeout = Rails.env.development? ? 0 : 25`. I suspect another error might surface.

Comment: @lobati That did the trick! I added the line and app started to work :) Can you explain it, please? I' d be happy to accept and upvote your answer if you add one as this really saved me.

Comment: answer with explanation added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it's not working in your case, but we've found `Rack::Timeout` to cause enough headaches in development that we just disable it. You can do this by setting the timeout to `0` in development mode. Just add a `config/initializers/rack_timeout.rb` file with the following:

```
Rack::Timeout.service_timeout = Rails.env.development? ? 0 : 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Would changing `<img src="<%= image_path('landing/laptop.png') %>" alt="laptop"/>`

to `<%= image_tag('landing/laptop.png') %>` work?

Here is a link to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

Comment: Thank you, however this does not work as error stays. I believe it is not related to the app code since it worked just fine in Cloud 9.

Comment: Could you post your landing_controller.rb as well

Comment: Added controller in Update above.